# How to get the record Id of the row in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Can any one please help me how to get the record Id of the button 
Row in LWC. The below code shows `undefined`

**JS:**

```
 handleRowAction(event) {
let rowId = event.detail.row.Id;
 console.log("selected Row " + rowId);
```

}

**HTML**

```
 <template for:each={studentdata} for:item="stu" for:index="index">
                        <div class="slds-p-top_large"  key={stu.Id}  >
                        <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade">
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-p-left_medium" style="width:100%;">
                                <div>{stu.FirstName} {stu.Id}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
                                <div class="slds-float_right">
                                    <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:add" title="Add Program"
                                        onclick={handleRowAction} key-field={stu.Id} data-record-id={stu.Id}  
                                         variant= "brand"> 
                                    </lightning-button-icon>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </h3>
                    </div>


                    </template>
```

Answer (score 2):

The event.detail.row.Id pattern only works on lightning-datatable. If you're rolling your own, you need to pass in the Id from the target:

```
handleRowAction(event) {
  console.log(event.target.dataset.recordId); // matches data-record-id
```